# Sitecore 8 - Adding images, callouts and videos in RTF field

Tags: sitecore, rtf, sitecore8, callouts

I am working on a requirement in Sitecore 8 according to which there is a Rich text field and the content author can not only add html data but can also add predefined call outs/renderings/images directly in page editor mode.

Is there any way I can achieve this ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We achieve this using Components in Experience Editor. As you create pages, we created components for Image, Video, Text and any Callouts. You will be able to drop components on the page based on specified placeholder settings. In my opinion it is the cleanest approach.

Comment: This is how we implemented it . Thanks much !!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like 'snippets' is the way to go for you. There are some posts on the web about how to add snippets to RTF fields:

- http://davetayls.me/blog/2011/02/07/adding-rich-snippets-to-sitecore-rich-text-editors/
- http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.ca/2010/11/richtext-editor-add-code-snippet-or.html
- http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Editors/Articles/2009/06/How%20to%20use%20snippets.aspx